# Is it possible to use XMLHttpRequest across Domains

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, cross-domain

Cross Site XMLHttpRequest from JavaScript can it be done?

I understand the limitations and why it is not generally able to work, but as of firefox 3.5 there is the

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

which is supposed to allow this to work.

It tells the browser that the server does not care if the request is sent to it from a domain that did not serve the page.

The code I am using is below.

```
function sendData(webservicePayload, callbackFunction) {
var request = null;
if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE
    try {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (E) {
            return 'Create XMLHTTP request IE';
        }
    }
} else { // code for Mozilla, etc.
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
/*
 * Setup the callback function
 */
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status < 300) {
        eval(callbackFunction);
    }
};
if (!request) {
    nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'Create XMLHTTP request', 'Failed');
    return;
}
/*
 * Setup the request headers
 */

request.open('POST','http://www.another.domain.co.uk/webservice.asmx', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Man','POST http://www.another.domain.co.uk/webservice.asmx HTTP/1.1');
request.setRequestHeader('MessageType', 'CALL');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"');
request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

request.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction','http://www.another.domain.co.uk/WebService/eService');
request.send(webservicePayload);
```

}

This is sending the correct request header

REQUEST

```
OPTIONS /webservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.another.domain.co.uk
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: https://my.domain.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control,content-type,man,messagetype,soapaction
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

and receiving an expected response header

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 13:43:27 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 44
```

As you can see the Orgin is specified in the request and the server responds with acceptance of any ("*") domain.

Why am I getting "Forbidden 403" as I feel that everything I have done is correct, I can't work out why?

Is anyone else getting this?

Do you know what is causing it?

Comment: Browsers, not all browsers support CORS

Comment: And for IE you need to use XDomainRequest instead of XMLHTTPRequest. But yes, cross domain XHR works very well, I use it to send data to imgur from my site for example. I recommend using a library to abstract the nasty details away.

Comment: Seems more like a server problem than a JS/browser problem. Check you APS code that is handles a OPTIONS request correctly.

Comment: As you can see from the header I am using Firefox 8.0
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
This solution is supposed to be generic, so I will change the code for XDomainRequest for IE8

Answer (score 4):

A CORs request actually consists of two physical HTTP requests: 1) The preflight request, and 2) the actual request. The request you posted above looks like the preflight request, since it is uses the HTTP OPTIONS method. So the first thing you have to do is verify that your server accepts OPTIONS requests (I believe this should just work, but it may explain why you are receiving a 403).

Next, you need a valid preflight response. The response to a preflight request must also contain the following two headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,cache-control,content-type,man,messagetype,soapaction
```

(See how these response headers are an echo of the Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers request headers). The Access-Control-Allow-Headers header should contain any custom request headers.

Once the browser receives this response, it knows that the preflight request has been accepted, and it makes the actual request. On the actual request, you only need the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

You can learn more about preflight requests and handling CORS requests here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: I will certainly be giving it a try.  There was no reason why it shouldn't have worked and this is a very comprehensive response.  Many thanks.